# Groovy remove text between parentheses in peer and parent child relationship

Tags: regex, groovy

In groovy, how to remove text between parentheses in peer and parent child relationship? Such as `a(b(c)d)` returns `a`. And `a(b)c(d)` returns `ac`?

Here is my code. But it can only handle one case. not both.

```
println name.replaceFirst( /\(.*\)/, '' ) 
println name.replaceAll( /\((.*?)\)/, '' )
```

Another solution is to detect if the parentheses match is peer to peer or parent to child and using the right RegEx. But I don't know how.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing, as regex won't cut it

```
def strip = { status, ch ->
  switch( ch ) {
    case '(': status.depth++ ; break
    case ')': status.depth-- ; break
    default:  status.str += (status.depth ? '' : ch)
  }
  status
}

assert 'a(b(c)d)'.inject( [ str:'', depth:0 ], strip ).str == 'a'
assert 'a(b)c(d)'.inject( [ str:'', depth:0 ], strip ).str == 'ac'
```

Answer (score 1):

Groovy uses Java regex, and there is no way in Java regex to do general bracket balancing (only regex implementations that supports recursive regex can do this). You are better off writing some simple code that loops through the string and matches the brackets.

You can force a regex solution if you assume the maximum level of nesting. However, this solution is **NOT** recommended.

- No nesting: `\([^()]*\)`
- [Nesting up to 1 level](http://www.rubular.com/r/zkp0GWyqyU): `\((?:[^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\)`
- [Nesting up to 2 levels](http://www.rubular.com/r/OfQHWpZVS6): `\((?:[^()]*|\((?:[^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\))*\)`
- Nesting up to n levels: `\((?:[^()]*|` + `<pattern at level n-1>` + `)*\)`

Note that you need to escape `\` when you specify the regex inside a string literal.