# What Javascript regex pattern can be used to capture text in potentially nested parentheses?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that can look like either of these `Adjuster, Carrier 3 (Carrier 3)` or `Adjuster, Carrier 3 (Carrier 3 (Test))`

I want to capture the contents within the first set of parentheses. My original regex pattern was `\((.+?)\)` (non-greedy), so I can capture the text as group #1.

```
var selectedOwnerText = /* GET THE TEXT FROM NODE/FIELD/ETC. */, 
    carrierName = '',
    rePattern = /\((.+?)\)/;

    if (selectedOwnerText != '') {
       carrierName = selectedOwnerText.match(rePattern);
       if (carrierName != null) {
          carrierName = carrierName[1];
       }
    }
 // Rest of code...
```

This works in the first text case, but in the second text case it grabs the outer parentheses e.g. `(Carrier 3 (Test)`.

Is there a regex pattern that can capture the text inside the outer parentheses, which may include parentheses as well?  I want either `Carrier 3` or `Carrier 3 (Test)` extracted from the above.

EDIT: I have just been told that this data field is free-form text, so anything could appear inside the outer parentheses.  So, I would need to capture everything inside the outer parentheses.

EDIT 2: I gave one user the correct answer, because it answered the original question (assuming only one set of inner parentheses).  Now that I know the text could be anything, a Javascript regex pattern is impossible, and I abandoned the regex approach.  I dived into the server-side code and surfaced a JSON literal of the data I needed, so as the page/Javascript is being created, I can use the data structure to get the content I need without worrying about what the string actually looks like.  Thanks to all who tried to help!

Comment: Is the nesting depth limited?

Comment: How many level of nesting? Limited levels can be parsed, but arbitrary levels is not possible with JS regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910158/groovy-remove-text-between-parentheses-in-peer-and-parent-child-relationship The question is in Groovy (Java), but it also applies for JS.

Comment: Are all your strings in the format `word, word (anything inside)` and are you testing each of the strings separately?

Comment: Have you tried this rePattern = /\((.+)\)/; ?

Comment: I've just been told that there could any number of characters between the outer parentheses.  It's free-form text.

Comment: @Stephen, Yeah bould could you have an infinite depth? `(sdlkj(test(test(test)))lksjdf)`?

Comment: Yeah, I just found out the string could be anything inside the outer parentheses.  This means I need to do something outside of regex to get my data. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the greedy version if and only if your string has the format `word, word (anything inside)` and not `word, word (anything inside) word (more parenthesized stuff)`:

```
/\((.+)\)/;
```

You'll get everything within the first opening parenthesis and the last closing parenthesis.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bK3qX5)

Comment: More generally, this solution assumes a single pair of outer parentheses.

Comment: I was told that "word, word (anything inside) word (more parenthesized stuff)" could happen since it is a free-form text field, although that is an edge case.  I may have to find another way to get at that specific piece of data than to rely on text in the DOM node and assume only one pair of outer parentheses.

Comment: @Stephen That'd be weird though. Which of the parens would you then need to get the contents of?

Comment: Oh, well, if people are even allowed to put unbalanced parens, then that's even worse! With missing brackets and multiple outer parens... it'd be a mess I don't think even a parser could handle.

Comment: Jerry, I'm giving you the correct answer, because it solves my original problem.  Because I just found out that the data I'm dealing with is free-form, I abandoned the regex approach.  I dived into the server-side code and surfaced a JSON literal of the data I needed, so as the page/Javascript is being created, I can use the data structure to get the content I need without worrying about what the string actually looks like.

Comment: @Stephen Thank you. I hope things turn out well for you. :)

Comment: @Jerry: I have an implementation without using regex.  It's going through testing now.  Thanks for the sounding board.